# How to load CSV file with https:// on shinyapps?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to load a csv-File from a https url and store it in a data frame.

On my local Windos it works without any problem, but as soon as i upload it to shinyapps.io i don't get the proper data out of the file.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tableOutput("bat")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    library(readr)
    bat <- read.csv("https://share.publibike.ch/index.php/s/S7wYDma8KE2CTqC/download")
    output$bat <- renderTable(bat)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the log-file of shinyapps.io i found this:

```
Warnung in file(file, "rt")
cannot open URL 'https://share.publibike.ch/index.php/s/S7wYDma8KE2CTqC/download': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warnung: Error in file: cannot open the connection to 'http://share.publibike.ch/index.php/s/S7wYDma8KE2CTqC/download'
```

I also tried several libraries: RCurl, curl, download.file but nothing worked so fare.

Comment: Are you sure it works on windows? Trying to access the file from a web browser I got: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php/s/S7wYDma8KE2CTqC/download on this server.

Comment: Yes, with RStudio and my web browser it works without any problem, should work also for you.

Comment: The problem seems to be the website you're trying to reach. Either you need a login that isn't set up on your shiny app, or the access is limited to some regions. Also, the url doesn't look like a regular .csv file, it might be the website's intended behaviour by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i will check the region point with the server provider.

Comment: @NewUser your suspicion was correct, the server provider has restricted access to Switzerland!